# What is an "American style shopping mall"?

Tags: meaning, adjectives, redundancy

Consider the phrase: "American style shopping mall?"

Implicit here is a large multi-story enclosed gallery with lots of shops on a passageway that connects the "Generators" (large department stores like Macy's or Bloomingdales that 'generate' customer traffic).

Is the adjective "American style" redundant?  Or what sort of other style would a "non-American style shopping mall" convey?

Comment: Well, not all malls in the US are as you describe.  (Perhaps in Brazil?)

Comment: The phrase "American-style shopping mall" (which I imagine refers to exactly the collection of major and minor tenants that you describe) may be  so designated not primarily to distinguish it from a "non-American-style shopping mall" but from an "American-style strip mall," in which a series of roughly equal-size commercial tenants share space in a (usually) one-story row of retail spaces with parking available in front of the block of retailers. In that case, the remaining issue would become, What does a non-American-style mall look like?—a question that may have an interesting answer.

Comment: It should be noted that what was arguably the first US mall (in the Chicago area) was not enclosed.  And many US malls (even some fairly large ones) are not multi-story.

Comment: Incidentally, what you call 'generators' are referred to in the US as 'anchors'. see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchor_store

Answer (score 1):

Having shopped in a variety of structures, including the early strip-type shopping malls in the US, the later fully enclosed ones in the US, Mexican markets with hundreds of separate stands all under one roof, French hypermarchés (where the floor managers wore roller skates) and more recently Walmarts in the US and Mexico, my answer is, you could probably get your point across without including "American style"; however, I think that it does add something to your phrase, and I recommend keeping it in there.